# AWS SDK for dot net core app to use AWS AppConfig

Tags: amazon-web-services, app-config, aws-sdk-net, aws-app-config

I'm trying to access application created in AWS AppConfig to retrieve the Configuration file. There's no proper documentation I found on the AWS Docs to receive the configuration through the dot net sdk using few methods.

ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/appconfig-retrieving-the-configuration.html

If any one can help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/appconfig-retrieving-the-configuration.html?

There is .NET SDK equivalent at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/AppConfig/TAppConfigClient.html

specifically method https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/AppConfig/MAppConfigGetConfigurationGetConfigurationRequest.html

Comment: I'm getting Content from the AWS AppConfig which is in MemoryStream. I used ConfigureAppConfiguration() to Add that jsonStream content as default configuration of applicatin. Is it best practice? @milang